# Get Time According to hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have a situation here. I am having a object like this.

```
var x ={
"startTime":"10:05Am",
"endTime":"12:05Pm"
}
```

So my requirement is i want a function which will return a variable with respective time

```
function getTime(x){
//do something
return timewitHrs;
}
```

timewitHrs should can be  something like this

```
[{"10am-11pm":55,"11pm-12pm":60,"12pm-1pm":5}]
```

Is there any way to sort this out

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your example output. How do you get 55,60 and 5 for the time ranges shown?

Comment: I mean that 10am-11am, time used is 55min,11am-12pm:60min,12pm-1am:5min, is it possible to get it time wise?

Comment: @argentum47: no its a data that shows how much time the app has been used i.e from morning 10:05 am to 11 am he has used it, so between 10 am to 11am he has used 55 min like wise 11am to 12 pm he has used 60 mins and 12pm-1pm 5 min

Comment: That makes no sense for the input that you've shown. You say you have the object `x`, but you've provided no explanation about how that relates to the output shown. In your comment you explained (sort of) what the 55, 60 and 5 *mean,* but not where that data actually comes from or how it relates to the input.

Comment: @nnnnnn:the x can be name say krishna, i entered into that app by 10:05 am and closed at 12:05 pm, the 55,60,5 are the minutes used in that specific hours.

Comment: You need to demonstrate an attempt. Start by creating a function to turn 12 hour time into 24 hour time.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code

```
var x ={
"startTime":"10:05am",
"endTime":"11:05am"
}
var start=moment(x.startTime,"hh:mma");
var end=moment(x.endTime,"hh:mma");
var output={};
output.duration=end.diff(start, 'm');//diference in minutes
output.range=start.startOf('h').format("hha")+"-"+end.endOf('h').add(1,'s').format("hha");
```

> output:{ duration: 60, range: '10am-12pm' }

Here I am calculating range based on start time & end time.
If you want something different let me know.

Comment: Is it possible to get 
output{duration :55,range:'10am-11am'},{duration:5,range:11am-12pm}

Comment: The thing is want i want how much minutes used in an hour. 55 min used in 10am-11pm. 5 min used in 11am-12pm